# comparing promise chaining patterns

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise

I have three promises,

Let's say, the result of first promise(foo) acts as input for second promise(bar) and the result of bar acts as input for third promise(baz).

```js
const foo = (flag) => new Promise((res, rej) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    flag ? res("foo resolved") : rej("foo rejected")
  }, 1000)
})


const bar = (flag) => new Promise((res, rej) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    flag ? res("bar resolved") : rej("bar rejected")
  }, 1000)
})


const baz = (flag) => new Promise((res, rej) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    flag ? res("baz resolved") : rej("baz rejected")
  }, 1000)
})


/*Now I can use these using one of following approaches */


foo(1).then(fooVal => {
  console.log(fooVal);
  return bar(fooVal).then(barVal => {
    console.log(barVal);
    return baz(barVal).then(bazVal => {
      console.log(bazVal);
    }).catch(err => { console.log(err, "--> err from untidy baz"); throw err; } )
  }).catch(err => { console.log(err, "--> err from untidy baz or bar"); throw err; })
}).catch(err => { console.log(err, "--> err from untidy baz or bar or foo"); throw err; })


foo(1).then(fooVal => { console.log(fooVal); return bar(fooVal) })
   .catch(err => { console.log(err, "--> err from foo"); throw err; })
   .then(barVal => { console.log(barVal); return baz(barVal) })
   .catch(err => { console.log(err, "--> err from foo or bar"); throw err; })
   .then(bazVal => { console.log(bazVal) })
   .catch(err => { console.log(err, "--> err from baz or bar or baz"); throw err; })
```

To me, the first approach looks very untidy but

When all the promises are resolved, the output seems to be similar,

**But there is significant change in the result if one of the promises is rejected.**

consider this snippet,
Here I rejected bar promise explicitly,

```js
const foo = (flag) => new Promise((res, rej) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    flag ? res("foo resolved") : rej("foo rejected")
  }, 1000)
})


const bar = (flag) => new Promise((res, rej) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    flag ? res("bar resolved") : rej("bar rejected")
  }, 1000)
})


const baz = (flag) => new Promise((res, rej) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    flag ? res("baz resolved") : rej("baz rejected")
  }, 1000)
})

foo(1).then(fooVal => {
  console.log(fooVal);
  return bar(false).then(barVal => {
    console.log(barVal);
    return baz(barVal).then(bazVal => {
      console.log(bazVal);
    }).catch(err => { console.log(err, "--> err from untidy baz"); throw err; } )
  }).catch(err => { console.log(err, "--> err from untidy baz or bar"); throw err; })
}).catch(err => { console.log(err, "--> err from untidy baz or bar or foo"); throw err; })
    
    
foo(1).then(fooVal => { console.log(fooVal); return bar(fooVal) })
   .catch(err => { console.log(err, "--> err from foo"); throw err; })
   .then(barVal => { console.log(barVal); return baz(false) })
   .catch(err => { console.log(err, "--> err from foo or bar"); throw err; })
   .then(bazVal => { console.log(bazVal) })
   .catch(err => { console.log(err, "--> err from baz or bar or baz"); throw err; })
```

**Which of the above approaches is better and which one should be preferred ?**

**Which of these is an anti-pattern, if any?**

Comment: As you noted, there is semantic difference in the two forms; they are not equivalent. Thus, "better" is whatever fits what you need to do. For tidiness, convert everything to `async`/`await`/`try`/`catch` instead of this promise hell.

Comment: Yes, I know async/await is very clean, also apart from semantic difference, there is also significant difference in error handling approaches. Did you tried to execute second snippet?

Comment: The error handling _is_ the semantic difference I was referring to :) `try { x(); try { y(); } catch ... } catch ...` different from `try { x(); } catch ...; try { y(); } catch ...`, they are not interchangeable, and you need to pick which one you need to use each time according to the circumstances you are facing, not blindly take one as canonically "better".